# React - merging 2 strings to get URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I join a link http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/ and {item.backdrop_path}, which provides the rest of the link?
For example in the end it should look like: http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/bcRFf5Qmw4XotFYAfj8fCS8PJy5.jpg

this is the code itself:

```
export default class MoviesSearch extends Component {
  render() {
    const {movieprop} = this.props;

    return (
      <ul className = "col-md-4 list-group">
        {
          movieprop && movieprop.slice(0,5).map((item ) =>
          <li key={item.id}>
            <h4>name:{item.title }</h4>
            <p>release date: {item.release_date}</p>
            <p>vote: {item.vote_average}</p>
            <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185{item.backdrop_path}"/> //NOT WORKING
          </li>
        )
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Right now it works fine for title, release date and vote, but I can not get the url.  The data is from themoviedb: 
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?certification_country=US&certification=R&sort_by=vote_average.desc&api_key=79eb5f868743610d9bddd40d274eb15d

Please let me know if my explanation is horrible and I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to concatenate a string in JSX? Here's how:

```
<img src={"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + item.backdrop_path} />
```

Alternatively, in ES6 you can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like this:

```
<img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${item.backdrop_path}`} />
```

---

A simple demo of the result, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2awvdsej/). (*Inspect the element to see the src url.*)